# drawImage() isn't working

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I am making an app for iPhone and Android using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript with PhoneGap. I'm using HTML5 canvas. My ctx.drawImage(); function isn't working, and I cannot figure out why. Here is my code.

```
var imageReady = false;
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
    imageReady = true;
};
image.src = "http://urlToImage.com";
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 180);
```

I verified the src link and it worked. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `drawImage` call should be inside the asynchronous callback (which is executed when the image has loaded). Currently it is being invoked *before* the image is loaded.

```
var imageReady = false;
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
    imageReady = true;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 180);
};
image.src = "http://urlToImage.com";
```

Comment: Awesome! I can't believe I was that stupid to not realize that. Thank you for your help!